# ServiceStack.OrmLite returning "empty records"

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I´m starting with ServiceStack and using OrmLite to access my database. I used the Northwind example that comes bundled and modified it to access a SqlServer Database.

I changed the name of the table (`Customer` to `Client`) and the POCO class (Customer.cs) attributes so they match the correct ones in my table. When the request is made the returned data consist on a array containing N empty objects being N the number of records on the desired table.

If I add/remove records to the table this action is reflected on the returned data. So, OrmLite is querying the table but I can´t understand why my records are not populated.

The original json output:

```js
{    
    Customers: [
        {Id:"...", CompanyName:"...", }, 
        {Id:"...", CompanyName:"...", }, 
        {Id:"...", CompanyName:"...", }
    ], 
    ResponseStatus: {...}
}
```

After modification, I'm receiving:

```js
{
     Clients: [
         {}, 
         {}, 
         {}
     ], 
     ResponseStatus: {}
}
```

Note the array with the N empty objects as value of the `Clients` key.

Comment: You need to post the relevant query code.

Comment: Make sure your data types match; a nullable db integer field should be mapped "int?" class property.